# What alternatives for sticky notes are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, stickynotes

I like the Sticky Notes very much, they are always on the desktop.

But I can't find it in Ubuntu since 12.04. Other programs like gnotes & Xjournal are not giving a feature to stay on the desktop.

So, is there any application similar to the old sticky notes in Ubuntu?

Comment: use reminder note from here http://getremindernote.com

Answer (score 217, accepted):

1. Good news: you can have **[Sticky Notes](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/pin-notes-on-your-desktop-with.html)** in Ubuntu.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
   ```
2. If you'd also like to try an alternative, I can suggest **[XPad](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/xpad-simple-sticky-notes-for-your-desktop)** as well, which should be in the official repositories.

Comment: Thank you !! Xpad works exactly what I was looking for .good application.

Comment: As a note for people coming in the future (speaking as someone who's used both of these) - stickynotes seems to have an issue where it keeps launching duplicate instances of itself and pollutes my system tray (among other annoyances) - xpad seems to just "work better".

Comment: Yep, sticky notes doesn't work with alt+tab. The moment you click on different window, it disappears. IMO, DO NOT INSTALL. Just 2 min ago installed xpad, works with Alt+Tab, allows visibility in all workspaces, maximizes, etc. Simple, works.

Comment: i second what people are saying. Do not install Sticky Notes. It's horrible. The default color is horrendous and there are no options. xpad works.

Comment: I cannot even get Sticky Notes to work (on Ubuntu 22.04). Clicking the icon and selecting "New Note" doesn't seem to do anything. I'll join the other commenters in recommending against installing this one. Xpad is not perfect, but did work out of the box for me.

Answer (score 134):

**xpad** deserves a try. Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xpad
```

[image: xpad]

Comment: Xpad is currently maintained.

Comment: @ArthurBorsboom OP may have been mistaken between [xpad](https://launchpad.net/xpad) which is in the repos and the one for Apple's MacOS. The latter is in fact no longer supported: http://getxpad.com/ but just to point out that it seems to be a completely different software.

Comment: Where it is stored?

Comment: It worked great in the past, but in a few recent years it became riddled with bugs (e.g. it doesn't remember last open notes and opens them all every time it's launched, it also crashes when I close the last note (or use "close all")). @PratikButani the notes are stored in ~/.config/xpad

Comment: "acheter chat" :)

Comment: This app is awful, constantly freezes, notes sometimes disappear. Wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: If anyone knows how, could you edit this post to include a link to or instructions for getting the xpad icon to show up in the unity panel?

Comment: @PratikButani The notes are stored in `$HOME/.config/xpad`.

Comment: No hotkeys or shortcuts other than copy+paste, not even to make the font bold, or to underline, etc. Big turndown for me.

Comment: To move the xpad, press ctrl and then move.

Comment: Great tool. Thanks. Is there a possibility to pin it on top of all other windows?

Comment: Seems to work, but there are some things I don't like — sharing here in case it helps others decide: 1) clicking the icon in the panel/systray toggles the sticky notes, or creates a new one if nothing exists; so after creating the first one, I need to right-click and select "New" to create a new one, which is not convenient when I want to quickly write something down. 2) Notes can only be resized if window decorations are enabled, but that has the downside of adding a title bar to the notes. 3) New notes are partially obscured by the systray, so they need to be moved down to be visible.

Answer (score 13):

**[Tomboy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/tomboy/)**

This is a note taking app for your Linux which also works on Mac and Windows platforms.

Features:

- Making notes
- highlight text
- bulleting
- change fonts
- link to email addresses

... and much more.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

[image]

[official site](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy)

Comment: this is not sticky...

Comment: this looks  ugly and as @insign mentioned, it's not sticky

Comment: Just tried it, and it supports `Latex` !!  To me, that eliminates all other choices :)

Comment: Ugly yes, but the one I was able to install at work where I can't change the repositories. So thank you.

Answer (score 5):

My preferred one is `xfce4-notes`. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-notes*
```

Comment: sadly I couldn't make this work outside Xfce (e.g. in Unity or elementaryOS) - it won't show an icon anywhere unless you use xfce4-panel

Answer (score 5):

Try the following command. For me it worked on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

`sudo snap install stickynotes`

[image: Screenshot of stickynotes]

These are even better than the Windows stickynotes. You can arrange multiple notes as tiles and them access them individually as needed. You can color code them based on priority or just to identify them distinctly. They also have multiple options like:

- Adding video
- Adding audio
- Touch mode
- Import
- Export
- Spelling suggestions as you write

Comment: @Kevin How did you add inline image? I was not able to find a way to do that.

Comment: I just added an exlamation mark. You can click on he edited link to see [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1190406/revisions)

Comment: I can't add text to the sticky. This is pretty bad

Comment: @Heisenberg I usually avoid snap packages. The majority of snap packages that I install on my computer don't work.

Answer (score 3):

I have found my self three more good tools and I would like add them here , may be that can help others in future .

knotes:

```
sudo apt-get install knotes
```

note(CLI):

```
sudo apt-get install note
```

knotes-mobile:

```
  sudo apt-get install knotes-mobile
```

Answer (score 3):

A mac like notes app. http://www.get-notes.com/

Comes with great features.

- Cross platform
- Auto save
- Search

Comment: just what I was looking for. Perfect. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not really a Ubuntu thing, but have found the Sticky Notes Chrome app really useful, specially because I have different workplaces and they sync through Google drive. It also offers formatting options, which lacks in some Linux options. Here's the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sticky-notes/nbjdhgkkhefpifbifjiflpaajchdkhpg/related?hl=en

Comment: Beware - I lost all my notes with this app! One day they disappeared and I never got them back :( I still have xml files in my drive but the app does not see them so I'm screwed. OT: does anyone know of a good xml parser to extract my notes from this pickle?

Answer (score 1):

For really quick notes, on Ubuntu Budgie we have QuickNote, an area to drop quick & short notes:

[image]

- Customizable size
- Customizable data location can be

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd throw my programme in for good measure: [Gnut](https://gitlab.com/jaysaurus/Gnut)

[image: Screenshot of Gnut]

I got a bit fed up with xnote and wrote a JavaFX-based sticky notes programme called Gnut some years back.  It's pretty basic but has served my colleagues and I well.  I've just added copy paste and put a more easy-to-install release up on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/jaysaurus/Gnut)

Answer (score 0):

I use conky with `/etc/conky/conky.conf` containing:

```
${exec head -n 16 /home/aaa/myfiles/todo/todo.txt | fold -w 50 -s}
```

source: 'conky' in http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/make-your-linux-desktop-send-alerts-that-you-cant-miss/
from google 'linux wallpaper reminder'

add command `conky -d -p 10` to 'session and startup' so conky start automatically during startup.

source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=140105
from google 'xfce conky not showing' result 1

Comment: Send a sample of the todo.txt contents.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but there's another software available in the current Ubuntu Software app (I'm on 18.04), that is *also* called Sticky Notes, but I don't think it is in anyway related to the [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/245030/132982) app suggested above.

The notes for it says the project page and GitHub page are at:

- https://github.com/playork/stickynotes
- https://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Diary-Organizers-Calendar/Playork-stickynotes.shtml.

It works well for me. Sometimes a little sluggish, but it does a good job of what I need it to. I also evaluated `xpad`, but this works for me. It looks you can sync it to DropBox, but I haven't needed to do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you **SimpleNote**.This application that works across different platforms and mobile devices, then you should take a look at Simplenote. Your notes stay updated across all your devices and stay organized so you can find notes quickly with instant searching and simple tags.

https://simplenote.com/

[image]

Imagesource: https://simplenote.com/2017/11/20/windows-and-linux-app-update-now-available-2/

Comment: web based.
I prefer google's Keep.

Comment: Back there, I used Simple Note. However, I prefer Google Keep and Microsoft OneNote.