# Tomboy Notes HiDPI

Tags: gnome, tomboy

I cant seem to get hidpi to work on tomboy notes. Is there an environment variable that needs to be set or is there absolutely no support for getting this to display well on hidpi devices?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use Indicator Sticky Notes software instead, I beleive it has more capabilities than tomboy or read [This other answer for other similar software options you can try](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245019/what-alternatives-for-sticky-notes-are-available)