# White rectangles on Plasma desktop (Updated)

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am having a problem with my desktop. I have ended up with three off-white rectangles on the desktop, each of which contain the name/title of a news item that I downloaded from a respectable linux news site. The "first" rectangle is approx. 56mm (hor.) x 33mm (ver.), the "second"" is approx. 56mm (hor.) x 58mm (ver.), and the "third" is approx. 56mm (hor.) x 58mm (ver.).

@DK Bose & @guiverc:
Thank you for your responses to my previous post which I have implemented. As you will see from the system info above, I have carried out a (Konsole-based) *release-upgrade* to a supported version and the original problem, as stated above, has persisted. I have also, as requested, supplied a screenshot.

My questions are :-

a) has anyone else ever experienced this type of desktop behaviour ?

b) does anyone know how I can clear these rectangles from the desktop ?

I should also state that I am using the Cube desktop and that these rectangles appear on every virtual desktop that comprises the Cube.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Stuart

[image: Current Plasma Desktop]

Comment: It looks almost like Sticky Notes or something.  Maybe one of these apps:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/245019/what-alternatives-for-sticky-notes-are-available

Comment: A KDE developer has suggested that you may have middle-clicked on the desktop thereby opening a "Notes" widget with contents of your clipboard. In that case, long-left click on each rectangle to get the option to remove each note.

Comment: **1:** Can you still reproduce the problem? I downloaded the exact same article from the same site using Firefox but don't see the issue. If you download other files from other sites does the same thing happen? Could this be due to a browser extension? **2:** What happens if you right-click on a rectangle? **3:** What does `xprop` or `xwininfo` tell you? If you have `wmctrl` installed, what does `wmctrl -lx` tell you? **4:** Have you installed some sort of widget or plasmoid? 5: Do the rectangles persist if you use a new wallpaper?

Comment: @Terrance: It would seem that DKBose has found the solution (see below). However, thank you for taking the time to provide a possible solution.

Comment: @DKBose: You seem to be correct in that I may have inadvertently middle-clicked while downloading the web page. Your solution of long-left clicking on each rectangle in turn did the trick by right-expanding a "handle"/whatever that included a trash can at the bottom. As often happens, an apparently insoluble problem ends up having a very simple solution. Thank you so much for all(!) the effort that you put into providing this solution.

Comment: @DKBose: To try to answer some of your questions:

Comment: @DKBose: First, oops! 1: Now that I know the solution it may be that I could reproduce the problem but I'd rather not take the chance. 2: When a rectangle is right-clicked, a multi-section context menu appears most of which is greyed-out. Selecting "Clear" or "Delete" only removes the text from the rectangle which remains. 3: I don't have xprop, xwininfo, or wmctrl installed (as far as I know). 4: I had not installed any new widgets or plasmoids before downloading the web page. 5: Yes. I did change the desktop wallpaper after(!) the problem arose and the rectangles did persist. Thank you again

Comment: Well, it seems that the act of middle-clicking on the desktop generates a Note with content of the clipboard. I myself don't use Notes (or middle-clicking). • `xprop` and `xwininfo` are tools already on your system. They could provide information about X-windows, but not about plasmoids. `wmctrl` isn't installed by default but can be used to list X-windows among other things. • Anyway, your issue is resolved!